# Singular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

I am trying to solve this differential equation, I have already obtained the general solution of the given equation in parametric form, however I do not know where to get the particular solution y = -1,Could you tell me if I am doing something wrong?

The equation $$ dy/dx=(dy/dx-1)e^{dy/dx}$$
We make $$ dy/dx=p$$
Then $$y=(p-1)e^{p}$$
$$⇒dy/dp=e^{p}+(p-1)(e^{p})$$
$$⇒dy/dp=e^{p}+(p-1)(e^{p})$$
$$⇒dy/dp=e^{p}+e^{p}-e^{p}$$
$$⇒dy/dp=e^{p}$$
$$⇒dy=e^{p}p dp$$
$$⇔pdx=e^{p} p dp$$
$$⇒dx=e^{p}dp$$
$$\int 1 dx=\int e^{p}  dp$$
$$⇒x=e^{p}+C$$
The general solution   is
$$x=e^{p}+C , y=(p-1)e^{p} $$

Comment: The DE gives $p=(p-1)e^p$

Comment: And $y=-1$ is meaningless. Maybe it's $y(0)=-1$ ?